# Regex in JS to get text between delimited characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I have been searching and trying to use Regex in JS to do one simple data extraction of text between delimited characters but NOT including the delimited characters . I thought it's something simple but I just couldn't get it.

```
Text = "This is a [sample] text to be [extracted] by Regex function."
Result I am looking for     = sample, extracted
Result I am not looking for = [sample], [extracted]
```

Can some one help please.

Comment: Use positive lookbehind and positivve lookahead, example: `/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positive lookbehind and positivve lookahead, example: `/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/`

e.g.

```js
let text = "This is a [sample] text to be [extracted] by Regex function."

let regex = /(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/g

console.log(text.match(regex))
```

Comment: Your code works in code snippet. When I try to do in the context of Google Sheets App Script, it returns an empty string which I think means no match. It seems like I have to use \\[ instead of \[ in the opening delimited character.

    var re = new RegExp("(?<=\\[).*?(?=\])","");
    dataobj = response.getContentText().match(re);

This one works instead. I wonder if it is the differences in goolge app scripts in JS implementation or it's me not knowledgable enough.

Comment: If you literally want '[' need to use '\' first, because '[' is a special character in regex, it's related to sets